# Pull username from input text in Watson Conversation

Tags: json, regex, watson-conversation, watson

As part of our Watson Conversation flow, we have one node that asks for usernames that we put into a context variable.

Most people just give us their username (janedoe12), and that is handled fine using this code.

```
{
  "context": {
    "username": "<?input_text?>"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Hi $username!"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is when people say "My username is janedoe12" that I can't seem to solve - I'm still trying to just pull out 'janedoe12'. We haven't often seen many other ways people give us their usernames (i.e. no one says "username janedoe12" or "my sn is janedoe12"), so we're not too worried about handling cases besides this one.

Here's what I have:

```
{
  "context": {
    "username": "<?input.text.extract('(?<=username is ).*')?>"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Hi $username!"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I feel like the problem is likely that I'm using the wrong RegEx style but I'm not quite sure how to go from here. I can get to this node fine, but it returns **$username** as *null*. Anyone have any suggestions on how to design this?

Comment: Try `extract('username\\s+is\\s+(.*)', 1)`

Answer (score 1):

I [blogged about this](https://sodoherty.ai/2016/09/11/what-is-your-name/) a long time ago.

Thankfully things have changed somewhat to make it easier for you. There is a BETA system entity called `@sys-person`. It can pick up a persons name.

Once you detect the entitiy, then you can just reference the input directly like so.

```
"username": "<? @sys-person ?>"
```

---

To expand out on this, because you are talking about a user name rather than a persons name. You are going to suffer the same issues as mentioned in the blog post.

Those being.

- Answering with "My name is"
- Refusing to give a name.
- Asking why would you want the name.
- Playing with the system to get a joke response.

There may be other conditions.

Here are two ways to approach it.

First, you can have the application layer hand over to conversation the user name, if they had to log into to talk to the chat bot. This means you don't need to ask the person, and it will be coming from a valid area.

Second, sometimes simply rewording how you speak to the user can negate any complex coding. If I say "What is your username?", someone can respond as you mentioned.

However if I say "Please enter your 6 digit user ID", then people are more likely to only enter in their ID.

At that point you can scan by using the following.

```
"username": "<? input.text.extract('^[A-Za-z0-9_]{6}') ?>"
```

If you don't detect the user ID you can then prompt them to type it in correctly.

Answer (score 0):

('username\s+is\s+(.*)', 1)

-from Wiktor Stribiżew